# why table scroll does not show up?

Tags: jquery

I am making my tables scrollable using this function:

```
$(function() {
        $('#tables-section table').each(function(){
            // if table > 4 rows, make scrollable
            if($(this).find('tbody tr').length > 4) {
                $(this).tableScroll({height:116}); // make scrollable
            }
        });

});
```

after the page is loaded the table element has the tableScroll class but the scroll bar does not show up.

Can anybody tell me what is missing?

Comment: Can u create a https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: did you try to make tbody a block display?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll/blob/master/README.md), the table needs to have a thead and a tbody. In the code, it is only checking for tbody. It's possible it could be trying to apply the scroll to tables that are missing the thead.

I was able to get this working just fine using your javascript snippet in the [demo](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll/blob/master/demo.html). I noticed that if I only had about 5 rows, the scrollbar didn't show up. But it would show up at about 6 or more. Maybe you could set the height to something like 80 instead?

Here is a JSFiddle showing 5 rows scrolling by setting the height to 80: https://jsfiddle.net/wrn27597/1/

Code is at the bottom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tables-section table').each(function(){
        // if table > 4 rows, make scrollable
        if($(this).find('tbody tr').length > 4) {
            $(this).tableScroll({height:80}); // make scrollable
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the table has its own thead and tbody. But it still does not work.

Comment: I updated my answer with another suggestion and a JSFiddle link.